# How to get better at testing your own code

Tags: testing

I am a relatively new software developer, and one of the things I think I should improve is my ability to test my own code. Whenever I develop a new functionality, I find it really difficult to follow all the possible paths so I can find bugs. I tend to follow the path where everything works. I know this is a well known issue that programmers have, but we don't have testers at my current employer and my colleagues seem to be pretty good at this.

At my organization, we do neither test-driven development nor unit testing. It would help me a lot but it's not likely that this will change.

What do you guys think I could do in order to overcome this? What approach do you use when testing your own code?

Comment: Just because your organization doesn't use TDD or unit testing doesn't mean that you can't, as long as you continue to meet your deadlines and produce quality code.

Comment: I guess Thomas beat me to it, but I'm in a similar situation.  I write very high-level expectations of what a code change should do, and write unit tests if or when I can (even though our company doesn't officially do unit testing).  You don't have to commit them, and they're great ways to learn how functions are supposed to act (or should act after you fix them).

Comment: @Brian, I think you should commit them regardless of whether others currently use them.  Perhaps showing good practice will get others to follow.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The job of a coder is to build things.

The job of a tester is to break things.

The most difficult is to break things you just built. You will succeed only by going over this psychological barrier.

Comment: -1 The job of a coder is to build things _that work_. That always involves some amount of testing. I agree that there is a need for a separate tester role, but it's not the only line of defense.

Comment: @Matthew Rodatus - The amount of testing involved on coder side only aims at verifying that what should work actually works. On tester side, the aim is to find bugs, not to observe that the code works.

Comment: That's different from your answer, and I agree with that more. But, I still don't agree fully. Writing quality code comes through practice as you learn to think through -- ahead of time -- the possibilities of failure. You don't learn to think through the possibilities of failure without learning to create those possibilities. I do not think coders should be the only line of defense, but they should be the first line of defense. The issue at stake is one of thoroughness and mastery of the craft.

Comment: I agree with Matthew here, the ultimate coder can both fix and break their code. Who is better to knock the house down; the guy off the street with a hammer, or the architect that has already spent a good amount of time understanding the construction of said house? This same concept applies to coding, but it is not nearly as easy as knocking a house down. I for one am intrigued to hear if there actually are any methods for getting better...

Comment: @mouviciel - false dichotomy. The job of a coder is to build things that work, and he does that by thinking a-priori under what conditions his code is supposed to work. And this is verified, at the least, by creating destructive test + some ad-hoc boundary analysis (again, **at the least**.) Also, a good coder works against specifications, and specifications (when valid) are always testable. So a good coder develops test that verify these requirements are met in code (and you typically do that by writing req. tests that fail initially until you have code that passes the tests.)

Comment: @mouviciel - moreover, a tester's job is to perform requirements verification. Breaking things might be (at times) part of a requirements verification process, but they are not one and the same. If a tester is doing nothing but *breaking things up*, then the focus is on the wrong thing (not unless the task at hand at that very moment is to perform destructive testing.)

Comment: @luis.espinal - What you describe in your first comment is basically TDD, which is a great process to apply for a coder. Remember though that TDD is not about testing but about specification. What you describe in your second comment is the process usually applied in waterfall processes, but this is clearly not what a tester should do. The job of a tester is to find bugs, not to find a test case that meets a requirement. At a girst glance it looks like the same but many real-life projects have a 100% coverage of tests against requirements and nevertheless still contain many bugs.

Comment: @Dave Lasley - This is precisely my point: the architect is not the best person to knock his house down: he is too proud of how strong it is to be able to see its defects. Only another architect (not the guy off the street) can bring an objective eye on the house and to find that the house may break under some specific conditions that the former architect was too blind to imagine.

Comment: @mouviciel - I'm breaking up my response in pieces since it is impossible to fully answer multiple statements in such small textboxes. *"TDD is not about testing but about specification"*. Never said otherwise. Also, I'm not sure how this does not apply to a coder since *he build things*, and one cannot build without specifications.

Comment: @mouviciel - *"What you describe in your second comment is the process usually applied in waterfall processes"* - it is not applied just to waterfall processes. Say, you are doing some type of agile methodology and you get a change request. That request is an specification of something a customer/user desires out of a system. You code it and either you do a complete test of it or you do your unit tests and let a tester do the final UA/integration test, both cases completing a verification of the original feature request (a verification of the system agains the spec implied by the feature.)

Comment: @luis.espinal - I upvoted your comment: I agree with you about the role of TDD in the coding process.

Comment: @mouviciel - *"The job of a tester is to find bugs, not to find a test case that meets a requirement."* - an intelligent testing environment just doesn't limit itself to blindly click-click-click and go *ooh, error*. There is a context in which the system is tested. You tell the tester *"in this release, we implement feature X that should do Y according to this process under these conditions"*. **That's an spec**. If the tester finds a problem of any kind with the system fulfilling that feature request, that spec, then he finds a bug. Bug-finding is spec verification.

Comment: @mouviciel - *"At a girst glance it looks like the same but many real-life projects have a 100% coverage of tests against requirements and nevertheless still contain many bugs"* - but that's independent of testing or requirement specification. Testing can never indicate absence of bugs, just a inability to find bugs to a certain degree. Specs are either explicit or implicit (*thou shall not give a 404 when clicking the shinny submit button*) and the verification of which has no bearing on the incomputability of determining if a system is error-free.

Comment: If debugging means killing bugs, is it logically evident that programming means `"making bugs"`? I read this somewhere or similar phrase, cannot just remember where. So instead of making things, coder needs to break things with bugs. Tester needs to build things by finding the flaws, cheers.

Comment: -1: While the answer has a grain or two of truth in it, I don't see how the answer is useful. You seem to be saying that to be better at testing, one has to get over the psychological barrier that's preventing them from being good at testing. But _how_?

Comment: @mouviciel > "the architect is not the best person to knock his house down: he is too proud of how strong it is". I disagree. A good architect considers the forces that will impose against his structure and compensates in the design to ensure a robust final product. Pride and professionalism are no partners.

Comment: @mouviciel > "On tester side, the aim is to find bugs, not to observe that the code works." Again, I disagree. A tester and a coder face the problem from different angles, but both roles seek to fully test functionality and to find bugs. Where the roles differ is in knowledge domains. A classical tester sees the application from the outside (i.e. black box). They are experts on the functional requirements of the app. A coder must be an expert on both the functional requirements and the code.

Answer (score 14):

Franciso, I'm going to make some assumptions here, based on what you've said:

"We don't do neither TDD nor unit testing. It would help me a lot but it's not likely that this will change."

From this, I suspect your team does not place a lot of value on testing or management will not budget time for the team to try and tidy up existing code and keep [technical debt](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/43948/how-to-convince-management-to-deal-with-technical-debt) to a minimum.

Firstly, you need to convince your team/management the value of testing. Be diplomatic. If management is keeping your team moving forward, you need to show them some facts, such as the defect rate for every release. Time spent fixing defects could be better spent on other things, such as improving the application and making it more adaptive to future requirements.

If the team and management in general are apathetic about fixing the code and you feel unhappy about it, you may need to look for another place to work, unless you can convince them as I have said. I've encountered this problem to different degrees in all places I've worked. It could be anything from lack of a proper domain model, to poor communication in the team.

Caring about your code and the quality of the product you develop is a good attribute and one you always want encourage in other people.

Answer (score 11):

If you code in C, Objective-C or C++ you can use the [CLang Static Analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) to critique your source without actually running it.

There are some memory debugging tools available: ValGrind, Guard Malloc on Mac OS X, Electric Fence on *NIX.

Some development environments provide the option to use a debugging memory allocator, that does stuff like fill newly allocated pages and newly freed pages with garbage, detect the freeing of unallocated pointers, and write some data before and after each heap block, with the debugger being called if the known pattern of that data ever changes.

Some guy on Slashdot said he got a lot of value out of single-stepping ever new line of source in a debugger.  "That's it" he said.  I don't always follow his advice, but when I have it has been very helpful to me.  Even if you don't have a test case that stimulates an uncommon code path, you can twiddle a variable in your debugger to take such paths, say by allocating some memory, then using the debugger to set your new pointer to NULL instead of the memory address, then stepping through the allocation failure handler.

Use assertions - the assert() macro in C, C++ and Objective-C.  If your language doesn't provide an assert function, write one yourself.

Use asserts liberally, then leave them in your code.  I call assert() "The test that keeps on testing".  I use them most commonly to check preconditions at the entry point of most of my functions.  That's one part of "Programming by Contract", which is built into the Eiffel programming language.  The other part is postconditions, that is, using assert() at function return points, but I find that I don't get as much mileage out of that as preconditions.

You can also use assert to check class invariants.  While no class is strictly required to have any invariant at all, most sensibly designed classes do have them.  A class invariant is some condition that is always true other than inside of member functions that might temporarily place your object into an inconsistent state.  Such functions always must restore the consistency before they return.

Thus every member function could check the invariant upon entry and exit, and the class could define a function called CheckInvariant that any other code could call at any time.

Use a code coverage tool to check which lines of your source are actually getting tested, then design tests that stimulate the un-tested lines.  For example you could check low memory handlers by running your app inside a VM that is configured with little physical memory, and either no swap file or a very small one.

(For some reason I was never privy to, while the BeOS could run without a swap file, it was highly unstable that way.  Dominic Giampaolo, who wrote the BFS filesystem, urged me never to run the BeOS without swap.  I don't see why that should matter, but it must have been some kind of implementation artifact.)

You should also test your code's response to I/O errors.  Try storing all your files on a network share, then disconnect your network cable while your app has a high workload.   Similarly disconnect the cable - or turn off your wireless - if you are communicating over a network.

One thing that I find particularly infuriating are websites that don't have robust Javascript code.  Facebook's pages load dozens of little Javascript files, but if any one of them fails to download, the whole page breaks.  There just has to be some way either to provide some fault tolerance, say by retrying a download, or to provide some kind of reasonable fallback when some of your scripts didn't download.

Try killing your app with the debugger or with "kill -9" on *NIX while it is right in the middle of writing a big, important file.  If your app is well-architected, the entire file will get written or will not be written at all, or maybe if it is only partially written, what does get written will not be corrupted, with what data that is saved being completely usable by the app upon re-reading the file.

databases always have fault-tolerant disk I/O, but hardly any other kind of app does.  While journaled filesystems prevent filesystem corruption in the event of power failure or crashes, they don't do anything at all to prevent the corruption or loss of end-user data.  That is the responsibility of the user applications, but hardly any other than databases implement fault-tolerance.

Comment: +1 lots of practical advice that doesn't need support from anyone else. The only thing I'd add is that assert is for documenting and checking conditions that cannot fail *unless there is a bug in the code*. Never assert things that could fail due to 'bad luck', such as an essential file not being found, or invalid input, etc.

Answer (score 10):

When I look at testing my code, I usually go through a series of thought processes:

1. How do I break this "thingy" down into a testable size chunks?  How can I isolate just what I want to test?  What stubs/mocks should I create?
2. For each chunk: How do I test this chunk to make sure that it responds correctly to a reasonable set of correct inputs?
3. For each chunk: How do I test that the chunk responds correctly to incorrect inputs (NULL pointers, invalid values)?
4. How do I test for boundaries (e.g. where values go from signed to unsigned, 8 bit to 16 bit, etc.)?
5. How well do my tests cover the code?  Are there any conditions I missed?  [This is a great place for code-coverage tools.]  If there is code that was missed and can never be executed, does it really need to be there? [That's a whole other question!]

The easiest way I have found to do this is to develop my tests along with my code.  As soon as I have written even a fragment of code, I like to write a test for it.  Trying to do all of the testing after having coded several thousand lines of code with non-trivial cyclomatic code complexity is a nightmare.  Adding one or two more tests after adding a few lines of code is really easy.

BTW, just because the company you work at and/or your colleagues don't do Unit Testing or TDD, doesn't mean you can't try them, unless they are specifically prohibited.  Perhaps using them to create robust code will be a good example for others.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the advice given in the other answers, I would suggest using [static analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_code_analysis) tools (Wikipedia has a list of a number of [static analysis tools for various languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis)) to find potential defects before testing begins as well as monitoring some metrics that relate to the testability of code, such as [cyclomatic complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity), the [Halstead complexity measures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halstead_complexity_measures), and cohesion and coupling (you can measure these with fan-in and fan-out).

Finding hard to test code and making it easier to test will, well, make it easier for you to write test cases. Also, catching defects early will add value to your entire quality assurance practices (which include testing). From here, getting familiar with unit testing tools and mocking tools will make it easier for you to implement your testing.

Comment: +1 for cyclomatic complexity.  "I find it really difficult to follow all the possible paths so I can find bugs" implies to me that the OP's code may need to be broken into smaller, less complex chunks.

Comment: @Toby Yeah, that was why I decided to throw in static analysis. If you can't test your code, you have problems. And if you have one problem with your code, there might be others. Use a tool to find potential warning flags, assess them, and correct as needed. You'll not only have more testable code, but more readable code as well.

Answer (score 3):

You could look into the possible usage of [Truth Tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) to help you define all of the potential paths in your code. It's impossible to account for all possibilities in complex functions, but once you have your handling established for all known paths, you can establish a handling for the else case.

Most of this particular ability is learned by experience though. After you've used a certain framework for a significant amount of time, you begin to see the patterns and earmarks of behavior that will let you look at a piece of code and see where a small change could cause a major error. The only way I can think of to increase your aptitude in this is practice.

Answer (score 3):

If like you said you don't need Unit testing I don't see any better approach than trying to break your own code manually.

Try to **push your code to the limits**. For example try to pass variables to a function exceeding the boundary limits. Do you have a function which is supposed to filter user input? Try to input different combinations of characters.

Consider the **user's point of view**. Try to be one of the users who will use your application or library of functions.

Comment: +1 for mentioning seeing things from the user's point of view.

Answer (score 3):

> but we don't have testers at my current employer and my colleagues seem to be pretty good at this

Your colleagues must be truly exceptional to not follow TDD or unit test and never generate bugs so on some level I doubt that they are not performing any unit testing themselves.

I am guessing that your colleagues are doing more testing than is being let on but because this fact isn't known by management then the organization suffers as a result because management gets the impression that true testing is not being performed and bug numbers are low thus testing is unimportant and time will not be scheduled for it.

Talk to your colleagues and try to figure out what kind of unit testing they are doing and emulate that.  At a later time you can prototype better ways to unit test and TDD attributes and slowly introduce these concepts to the team for easier adoption.

Answer (score 2):

- Write your tests before you write your code.
- Any time you fix a bug that wasn't caught by a test, write a test to catch that bug.

You should be able to get coverage on what you write even if your organization doesn't have full coverage. Like so many things in programming, the experience of doing it again and again one of the best ways to be efficient at it.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to all the other comments, since you say your colleagues are good at writing non-happy-path tests, why not ask them to pair with you on writing some tests.

The best way to learn is be seeing how it's done and pulling in what you learn from that.

Answer (score 2):

Black box testing! You should be creating your classes/methods with testing in mind. Your tests should be based on the specification of the software and should be clearly defined on your Sequence diagram (via use cases).

Now since you may not want to do test driven development...

Put input validation on all incoming data; don't trust anyone. The .net framework has throws a lot of exceptions based on invalid arguments, null references and invalid states. You should already be thinking of using input validation on the UI layer so it's the same trick in the middle-ware.

But you should really be doing some sort of automated testing; that stuff saves lives.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience

Test unit, if it is not completely automatic,it is useless. It is more like a  Pointy Haired Boss could buy. Why?, because Test Unit promised you to save time (and money) automating some test process. But, some test unit tools do the opposite, it force programmers to work in some weird fashion and force other to create over-extend test. Most of the time, it will not save working hour but increase moving time from QA to developer.

UML is another time waster. a single whiteboard + pen could do the same, cheaper and quickly.

BTW,How to be good at coding (and avoid bugs) ?

- a) atomicity.  One function that do one simple (or a few single task).  Because it is easy to understand, it is easy to track and it is easy to solve it.
- b) Homology. If, for example, you call a database using a store procedure then do for the rest of the code.
- c) Identify,reduce and isolate "creative code". Most of the code is pretty much copy & paste. Creative code is the opposite, a code that is new and it act as a prototype, it can fail. This code is prone of logic bug, so it is important to reduce, isolate and identify it.
- d) "Thin ice" code, is the code that you know that it is "incorrect" (or potentially dangerous) but still is needing, for example unsafe code for a multi task process.  Avoid if you can.
- e) Avoid black box code, this include code that it is not done by you (for example framework) and expression regular. It is easy to miss a bug with this kind of code. For example, i worked in a project using Jboss and i found not one but 10 error in Jboss (using the latest stable version), it was a PITA to find those.   Avoid specially Hibernate, it hide the implementation, hence the bugs.
- f) add comments in your code.
- g) user input as source of bugs. identify it. For example, SQL Injection is caused by a user input.
- h) Identify bad element of the team and separate the task assigned.   Some programmers are prone to screw the code.
- i) Avoid unnecesary code. If, for example, the **class** need **Interface** then use it, otherwise avoid to add irrelevant code.

a) and b) are key.  For example, i had a problem with a system, when i clicked in a button (save) it didn't save the form.  Then i did a checklist:

- the button works?... yes.
- the database store something?.  no, so the error was in a middle step.
- then, the class that store in the database work?. no <-- ok, i found the error. (it was related with database permission).  Then i checked not only this procedure but every procedure that do the same (because the homology of the code).  It took me 5 minutes to track the bug and 1 minute to solve it (and many other bugs).

And a sidenote

> Most of the time **QA suck** (as a separate section of Dev), it is useless if they are not worked in the project. They do some generic test and nothing else much. They are unable to identify most logic bugs. In my case, i was working in a prestigious bank, a programmer finished a code then send it to QA. QA approved the code and was put in production... then the code failed (an epic fail), do you know who was blamed?. yes, the programmer.

Answer (score 2):

A tester and a programmer face the problem from different angles, but both roles should fully test functionality and find bugs. Where the roles differ is in focus. A classical tester sees the application from only the outside (i.e. black box). They are experts on the functional requirements of the app. A programmer is expected to be an expert on both the functional requirements and the code (but tends to focus more on the code).

*(It depends on the organization whether programmers are explicitly expected to be an expert on requirements. Regardless, the implicit expectation is there -- if you design something wrong, you -- not the requirements person -- receive the blame.)*

This dual expert role is taxing on the mind of the programmer and, excepting the most experienced, can decrease proficiency in requirements. **I find that I must mentally shift gears to consider the users of the application.** Here is what helps me:

1. **Debugging**; set breakpoints in the code and run the application. Once you hit a breakpoint, step through the lines as you interact with the application.
2. **Automated testing**; write code that tests your code. This only helps at tiers below the UI.
3. **Get to know your testers**; they may know the application better than you do, so learn from them. Ask them what the weaknesses of your application are, and what tactics they use to find bugs.
4. **Get to know your users**; learn to walk in your users' shoes. The functional requirements are the fingerprint of your users. There are often many things your users know about the application that may not come through clearly in the functional requirements. As you understand your users better -- the nature of their work in the real world and how your application is supposed to help them -- you'll understand better what the application is supposed to be.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to work on two fronts. One is political, getting your organization to adopt testing at some level (with the hope that over time they will adopt more). Talk to QA engineers outside your workplace. Find [lists of QA books](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/software_testing_qa_books.htm). Poke around [relevant wikipedia articles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_quality_assurance). Familiarize yourself with QA principles and practices. Learning this stuff will prepare you to make the most convincing case you can in your organization. Good QA departments do exist and they do add considerable value to their organizations.

As an individual developer, adopt strategies to use in your own work. Use [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) yourself by co-developing code and tests. Keep tests clear and well maintained. If asked why you're doing this, you can say you are preventing regressions and it keeps your thought process better organized (both of which will be true). There is an [art to writing testable code](http://misko.hevery.com/about/), learn it. Be a good example for your fellow developers.

Partly I'm preaching to myself here, because I do way less of this stuff than I know I should.